# How to add a term ALIAS(!) to content URL pattern?

Tags: path-aliases

I have latest Panopoly distribution installed (with Drupal 7).

What I need:

- my content items of a certain content type to have the f-g URL:

"vocab term URL alias"/"Node-title"

(first part of the URL should be term alias(!), not the term name as I have my term names in Cyrillic).

What I did:

- created the vocabulary with Terms
- added the term field to the content type

What I managed to get:

- I have a nice URL of that type: "term name"/"node-title". But I need
  the term alias instead of term name.

I have looked for the answer but no dice so far.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the [term:url:path] token? This should grab the aliased path, there is also the [term:url:unaliased:path] token for getting the unaliased path.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pathauto module](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module, it is exactly do what you want, look at the pathauto token exists there something like `[term:url:path]` can help you.

> The Pathauto module automatically generates URL/path aliases for
>   various kinds of content (nodes, taxonomy terms, users) without
>   requiring the user to manually specify the path alias. This allows you
>   to have URL aliases like /category/my-node-title instead of /node/123.
>   The aliases are based upon a "pattern" system that uses tokens which
>   the administrator can change.